# Error in Lang's definition of weak topology?

Tags: general-topology

On page 23-24 of his *Real and Functional Analysis* (3e) Serge Lang claims

> Let $Y$ be a topological space and let $\mathscr{F}$ be a family of
>   mappings $f \colon X \to Y$ of $X$ into $Y$. Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the
>   family of all subsets of $X$ consisting of the sets $f^{-1}(W)$ where
>   $W$ is open in $Y$ and $f$ ranges over $\mathscr{F}$. Then we leave to
>   the reader the verification of the following facts:
>
> 1. $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a topology on $X$, i.e. satisfies
>              conditions **B2** and **B2**.
> 2. ...

Here **B1** and **B2** are given on p. 23

> **B1**. Every element of $X$ lies in some set in $\mathscr{B}$.
>
> **B2**. If $B$, $B'$ are in $\mathscr{B}$ and $x \in B \cap B'$ then there exists some $B''$ in $\mathscr{B}$ such that $x \in B''$ and
>   $B'' \subset B \cap B'$.

It seems to me that the $\mathscr{B}$ defined in the first quote from Lang need not satisfy the property **B2** in the second quote.

For example, take $X=\Re^2$ , $Y=\Re$, $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1$, $g(x_1,x_2)=x_2$, $\mathscr{F} = \{f,g\}$, $I=(0,1)$, $B=f^{-1}(I)$, $B'=g^{-1}(I)$.

Then $B \cap B' = I \times I$ but no subset of this set can be an inverse image under either $f$ or $g$ of any subset of $\Re$.

Am I right in believing that this is an error in the book?

Comment: The base of the weak topology consists of all finite intersections of sets like $f^{-1}(W)$, as $f$ ranges in $\mathcal{F}$ and $W$ over the open subsets of $Y$. It seems to me that Lang's $\mathcal{B}$ is only a sub-base.

Comment: Right, it's a mistake. $\{ f^{-1}(W) : f \in \mathscr{F}, W \subset Y \text{ open}\}$ is only a subbase.

Answer (score 1):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

The question has been answered in comments.

You are right, it is a mistake. Lang's $\mathscr{B}$ is in general only a subbase.