The base for the weak topology is actually a base
I am reading Real and Functional Analysis by Serge Lang and I am having problems with this:
Let $Y$ be a topological space and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of mappings $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of $X$ into $Y$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the family of all subsets of $X$ consisting of the sets $f^{-1}(W)$, where $W$ is open in $Y$ and $f$ ranges over $\mathcal{F}$.
I just need to show that if $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal{B}$ and $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, then there exist a $B_3\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B_3\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$.
My english is poor. Sorry if I have grammar errors.

It is not. $\mathcal{B}$ is only a subbase. As an example, let $Y = {1, 2}$ be equipped with discrete topology, $X = {1, 2, 3}$, $\mathcal{F}$ contains two mappings $f_1 = {(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2)}$ and $f_2 = {(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2)}$. Then ${1, 2}, {2, 3} \in \mathcal{B}$ but ${2} = {1, 2} \cap {2, 3} \notin \mathcal{B}$.

This has also been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474461/error-in-langs-definition-of-weak-topology?rq=1

@DavidGao Thank you for the counter example. I lost 3 hours of my life trying to show something that is not true :')

@DavidGao Do you know what is the actual base for the weak topology?

It’s just finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{B}$, or, to put it another way, sets of the form $f_1^{-1}(W_1) \cap \cdots \cap f_n^{-1}(W_n)$, with $f_1, \cdots, f_n \in \mathcal{F}$ and $W_1, \cdots, W_n \subset Y$ open.
